# Elasticsearch and Kibana 7 on same host, Kibana service won't run

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to install elasticsearch and kibana on a single Ubuntu 18 vm per the docs. [Elasticsearch Installation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/getting-started-install.html) and [Kibana Installation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.0/install.html)

NOTE:
- I set the ES_HEAP_SIZE env var to half the memory of the VM OS
- I set netplan for a static IP on the VM: 10.1.2.10 or whatever
- I set the ulimits to unlimited so Lucene can have free reign over documents
- I add the Elasticsearch service to start on reboot
- I configure the yml file:
network.host: 0.0.0.0

Elasticsearch works fine once it has been installed and configured per the docs.

After installing Kibana, enabling the service, starting the service, configuring the yml, restarting the service, etc

the service will not run

I have tried combinations like the following for the kibana.yml file:

```
server.host: "localhost"

server.host: "localhost"
elasticsearch.hosts: ["localhost:9200"]

server.host: "localhost:5601"
elasticsearch.hosts: ["localhost:9200"]

server.host: "0.0.0.0"
elasticsearch.hosts: ["localhost:9200"]

server.host: "10.1.2.10"
elasticsearch.hosts: ["10.1.2.10:9200"]

server.host: "10.1.2.10:5601"
elasticsearch.hosts: ["10.1.2.10:9200"]

server.host: "0.0.0.0"
elasticsearch.hosts: ["10.1.2.10:9200"]
```

etc, etc, etc

Can anyone please help with this config? Everything I can find seems to leave things "localhost" but I am assuming because I am running this on vm and accessing from another this is the problem with config/Kibana. As I said I am able to access the 10.1.2.10:9200 message that Elasticsearch returns from that other machine just fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for answering my own, but in case someone has the same issue it might save you some time.

In my case it did work actually I just wasn't waiting on it long enough. It took a little over a minute for the kibana service to run I suppose because after waiting approx that long the web page came up. Although I was using

```
service --status-all
```

when I was checking and that never goes to [+] even after it is running.